# Android app force closes when playing next song in array list

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm creating an android app (for my own use) that lets me listen to my favourite songs from GTA V. 
Media Player streams the mp3 tracks from my dropbox account and all this works fine.

The problem is that after the first song finishes I want it to play the next song however when I run the app after the first song finishes playing the app crashes instead of playing the next song in the list.

Can somebody help me fix this issue i'm having?

thanks.

**Code**

```
public class channelx extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    Button play, pause, home, refresh;
    protected Dialog mSplashDialog;

     private int playlistPos = 0;
        private List<Uri> myUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        private MediaPlayer sdrPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.channelx);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(channelx.this);

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        final Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                t.cancel(); 
            }
        }, 5000); 

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);

         myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/4ANlGRms"));
         myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/TpmxsqGJ"));

         myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/rbkYtuNI"));
         myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/JYVHp9nm"));
         myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/xWLATUQp"));
         myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/WzV2TzFu"));
            // Add the others as well...

            initSong(myUris.get(playlistPos));

            sdrPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    sdrPlayer.reset();

                    playlistPos++;
                    initSong(myUris.get(playlistPos));


                    sdrPlayer.start(); // Start it as well if you wish
                }
            });



        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sdrPlayer.start();
            }
        }
        );


        pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sdrPlayer.pause();
            }
        });

        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(channelx.this);
                builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave this station? Playback will be stopped.");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);
                builder1.setPositiveButton("Continue",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        sdrPlayer.stop();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(channelx.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                builder1.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();

            }
        });

        refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sdrPlayer.stop();
                Intent intent = new Intent(channelx.this, channelx.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }

    public void initSong(Uri myUri) {
        try {
            sdrPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            sdrPlayer.setDataSource(this, myUri);           
            sdrPlayer.prepareAsync(); // don't use prepareAsync for mp3 playback
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(channelx.this,
                       "Please turn on WiFi and try again",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }




}
```

**LogCat**

```
05-26 15:37:14.574: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:-1
05-26 15:37:14.574: D/MediaPlayer(16744): sense_version:5.5
05-26 15:37:14.574: D/MediaPlayer(16744): ver s1:   55000
05-26 15:37:14.574: D/MediaPlayer(16744): ver s2:   55000
05-26 15:37:14.664: V/MediaPlayer(16744): network type=wifi
05-26 15:37:14.664: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:37:14.694: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-26 15:37:14.694: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() in
05-26 15:37:14.704: D/MediaPlayer(16744): SystemProperties.get htc.audio.mirrorlink.status: 
05-26 15:37:14.704: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false +
05-26 15:37:14.704: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false -
05-26 15:37:14.704: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() out
05-26 15:37:14.754: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 8
05-26 15:37:22.833: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (1, 902)
05-26 15:37:22.833: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:22.833: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 5
05-26 15:37:22.833: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 1
05-26 15:37:22.853: E/MediaPlayer(16744): Should have subtitle controller already set
05-26 15:37:24.044: D/[MediaPluginDLNA](16744): [getIsRegionSupported] sRegionCode: 6
05-26 15:37:24.044: D/[MediaPluginDLNA](16744): not in Mirror mode
05-26 15:37:24.044: D/MediaPlayer(16744): doStart() in
05-26 15:37:24.044: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Htc_getIntParameter = 902
05-26 15:37:24.184: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 6
05-26 15:37:25.115: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 7
05-26 15:37:26.176: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (703, 0)
05-26 15:37:26.176: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (701, 0)
05-26 15:37:26.176: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:26.186: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:27.177: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (702, 0)
05-26 15:37:27.207: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:28.238: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 7
05-26 15:37:29.370: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (703, 0)
05-26 15:37:29.370: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (701, 0)
05-26 15:37:29.370: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:29.370: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:30.391: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (702, 0)
05-26 15:37:30.401: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:31.412: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 7
05-26 15:37:31.612: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (703, 0)
05-26 15:37:31.612: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (701, 0)
05-26 15:37:31.612: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:31.612: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:37:32.433: W/MediaPlayer(16744): info/warning (702, 0)
05-26 15:37:32.433: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
05-26 15:39:16.584: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 7
05-26 15:39:16.764: E/MediaPlayer(16744): internal/external state mismatch corrected
05-26 15:39:16.774: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 2
05-26 15:39:16.774: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() in
05-26 15:39:16.814: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:16.814: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:16.824: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:16.864: V/MediaPlayer(16744): network type=wifi
05-26 15:39:16.864: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:16.894: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-26 15:39:16.894: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() in
05-26 15:39:16.894: D/MediaPlayer(16744): SystemProperties.get htc.audio.mirrorlink.status: 
05-26 15:39:16.904: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false +
05-26 15:39:16.904: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false -
05-26 15:39:16.904: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() out
05-26 15:39:16.904: D/[MediaPluginDLNA](16744): [getIsRegionSupported] sRegionCode: 6
05-26 15:39:16.904: D/MediaPlayer(16744): doStart() in
05-26 15:39:16.904: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Htc_getIntParameter = 0
05-26 15:39:16.904: E/MediaPlayer(16744): start called in state 4
05-26 15:39:16.904: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (-38, 0)
05-26 15:39:16.904: D/MediaPlayer(16744): start() out
05-26 15:39:16.904: D/MediaPlayer(16744): U58 Send PlaybackCompleteEvent
05-26 15:39:16.924: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 100
05-26 15:39:16.924: E/MediaPlayer(16744): Error (-38,0)
05-26 15:39:16.924: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() in
05-26 15:39:16.924: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:16.924: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:16.934: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (1, -107)
05-26 15:39:16.934: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:16.934: V/MediaPlayer(16744): network type=wifi
05-26 15:39:16.934: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:16.934: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-26 15:39:16.934: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() in
05-26 15:39:16.934: D/MediaPlayer(16744): SystemProperties.get htc.audio.mirrorlink.status: 
05-26 15:39:16.934: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false +
05-26 15:39:16.934: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false -
05-26 15:39:16.934: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() out
05-26 15:39:16.934: D/[MediaPluginDLNA](16744): [getIsRegionSupported] sRegionCode: 6
05-26 15:39:16.934: D/MediaPlayer(16744): doStart() in
05-26 15:39:16.944: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Htc_getIntParameter = 0
05-26 15:39:16.944: E/MediaPlayer(16744): start called in state 4
05-26 15:39:16.944: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (-38, 0)
05-26 15:39:16.944: D/MediaPlayer(16744): start() out
05-26 15:39:16.944: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 100
05-26 15:39:16.944: E/MediaPlayer(16744): Error (1,-107)
05-26 15:39:16.944: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() in
05-26 15:39:16.944: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:16.944: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:16.944: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:16.944: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (1, -107)
05-26 15:39:16.955: V/MediaPlayer(16744): network type=wifi
05-26 15:39:16.955: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:16.965: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-26 15:39:16.965: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() in
05-26 15:39:16.965: D/MediaPlayer(16744): SystemProperties.get htc.audio.mirrorlink.status: 
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false +
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false -
05-26 15:39:16.975: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() out
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/[MediaPluginDLNA](16744): [getIsRegionSupported] sRegionCode: 6
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): doStart() in
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Htc_getIntParameter = 0
05-26 15:39:16.975: E/MediaPlayer(16744): start called in state 4
05-26 15:39:16.975: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (-38, 0)
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): start() out
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 100
05-26 15:39:16.975: E/MediaPlayer(16744): Error (1,-107)
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() in
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:16.975: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:16.985: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (1, -107)
05-26 15:39:16.985: V/MediaPlayer(16744): network type=wifi
05-26 15:39:16.985: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:16.995: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-26 15:39:16.995: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() in
05-26 15:39:16.995: D/MediaPlayer(16744): SystemProperties.get htc.audio.mirrorlink.status: 
05-26 15:39:16.995: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false +
05-26 15:39:16.995: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false -
05-26 15:39:16.995: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() out
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/[MediaPluginDLNA](16744): [getIsRegionSupported] sRegionCode: 6
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/MediaPlayer(16744): doStart() in
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Htc_getIntParameter = 0
05-26 15:39:17.005: E/MediaPlayer(16744): start called in state 4
05-26 15:39:17.005: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (-38, 0)
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/MediaPlayer(16744): start() out
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 100
05-26 15:39:17.005: E/MediaPlayer(16744): Error (1,-107)
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() in
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:17.005: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:17.015: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (1, -107)
05-26 15:39:17.015: V/MediaPlayer(16744): network type=wifi
05-26 15:39:17.015: D/MediaPlayer(16744): mIsAboveSense55:1
05-26 15:39:17.015: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-26 15:39:17.025: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() in
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/MediaPlayer(16744): SystemProperties.get htc.audio.mirrorlink.status: 
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false +
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/MediaPlayer(16744): set AwesomePlayer LPA flag to false -
05-26 15:39:17.025: I/MediaPlayer(16744): setLPAflag() out
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/[MediaPluginDLNA](16744): [getIsRegionSupported] sRegionCode: 6
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/MediaPlayer(16744): doStart() in
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Htc_getIntParameter = 0
05-26 15:39:17.025: E/MediaPlayer(16744): start called in state 4
05-26 15:39:17.025: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (-38, 0)
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/MediaPlayer(16744): start() out
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/MediaPlayer(16744): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 100
05-26 15:39:17.025: E/MediaPlayer(16744): Error (1,-107)
05-26 15:39:17.025: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() in
05-26 15:39:17.035: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:17.035: D/MediaPlayer(16744): reset() out
05-26 15:39:17.035: W/dalvikvm(16744): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4167de18)
05-26 15:39:17.035: E/MediaPlayer(16744): error (1, -107)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744): Process: com.example.gtavradio, PID: 16744
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at com.example.gtavradio.channelx$2.onCompletion(channelx.java:75)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3162)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
05-26 15:39:17.045: E/AndroidRuntime(16744):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 15:39:19.918: D/Process(16744): killProcess, pid=16744
05-26 15:39:19.918: D/Process(16744): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:131 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

**EDIT: ignore some of the daft commentary on my code**

**NEW LOG**

```
05-26 16:20:11.884: E/MediaPlayer(1530): attachNewPlayer called in state 128
05-26 16:20:11.884: W/dalvikvm(1530): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4167de18)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530): Process: com.example.gtavradio, PID: 1530
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530): java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1236)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1203)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1137)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1032)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at com.example.gtavradio.channelx.initSong(channelx.java:155)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at com.example.gtavradio.channelx$2.onCompletion(channelx.java:78)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3089)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
05-26 16:20:11.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1530):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT this code now doesn't crash the app but it still doesn't play the next song automatically, I have to repress play to get it to play the next song**

```
sdrPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    sdrPlayer.stop();
                            sdrPlayer.reset();


                    playlistPos++;
                    if (playlistPos == myUris.size()) {
                        playlistPos = 0;
                    }
                    initSong(myUris.get(playlistPos));

                    //sdrPlayer.start(); // Start it as well if you wish
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an array index out of bounds exception -- I assume this is caused by

```
playlistPos++;
initSong(myUris.get(playlistPos));
```

Just check that the playlistPos isn't greater than the playlist size:

```
playlistPos++;

if (playlistPos == myUris.size()) {
    playlistPos = 0;
}

initSong(myUris.get(playlistPos));
```

Which will loop the playlist for you.

Now, to prevent the other error you're getting, try removing the `sdrPlayer.start()` from the `onCompletionListener`, and only call start when the player is prepared.

```
sdrPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        sdrPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

**EDIT :** Here is some working code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private int playlistPos = 0;
    private List<Uri> playlist;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        playlist = createPlaylist();
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        initMediaPlayer();
        initSong();
    }


    private void initMediaPlayer() {
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                playlistPos++;

                if (playlistPos == playlist.size()) {
                    playlistPos = 0;
                }

                initSong();
            }
        });

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }


    private void initSong() {
        mp.reset();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(this, playlist.get(playlistPos));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mp.prepareAsync();
    }


    private List<Uri> createPlaylist() {
        List<Uri> myUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/4ANlGRms"));
        myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/TpmxsqGJ"));
        myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/rbkYtuNI"));
        myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/JYVHp9nm"));
        myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/xWLATUQp"));
        myUris.add(Uri.parse("https://db.tt/WzV2TzFu"));
        return myUris;
    }

}
```

Comment: When I try this it doesn't even play a song. it just returns in the log `start called in state 0 error - 38`

Comment: This means that the media player hasn't been prepared. There more info about the [MediaPlayer state here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram)

Comment: Did you make sure you still call `initSong` ?

Comment: should I call initSong in the if statement or just underneath it?

Comment: Underneath. You need to call `initSong` so that the player can prepare, but you shouldn't call it until you know the correct playlist position. For this reason, you should add it underneath, so that it's still called regardless of whether or not the playlist starts at the beginning again.

Comment: Okay I've tried that and now when I press play the Logcat goes wild. the main error i'm seeing is `(-38,0)  start called in state4` the logcat is continuously showing this error

Comment: That solved the logcat error but now it's still crashing when it goes to play the next song. see the updated logcat up the top for my errors. I have no idea why this isn't working :S

Comment: add `sdrPlayer.reset();` to the very beginning of your `initSong` method

Comment: Error (1, -107) and it sends the log cat going wild again :(

Comment: Okay I put the reset just outside the try catch and it works. But I have to press play again for it to play the next song. How can I just get it to play by itself?

Comment: I've included some working code. I suggest that, rather than copy and paste it, you have a read through and try and get an idea of why it works. That way, you can adjust it to fit your application, and wire it up to your buttons etc. Please note that there is a delay of a few seconds before it starts playing -- this is because the MediaPlayer is buffering the stream. It will start to play as soon as it's buffered.

Answer (score 0):

The error code is related to the Array size.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6
```

Somewhere in the Code your code turns out to play the next song with the Index number of 6. I am not sure whether this gets from the Dropbox API or you're making it up. But the error is something like this

```
int[6] songIds = [10, 14, 12, 54, 24, 54];
/* then somewhere while playing 
 * you reference the array as */
songIds[6];
```

This is clear sign that the Song you're trying to play isn't a part of the Array. You need to play the song number 5 or you need to go back to the first song. You should remember that the Array index starts from 0 and go upto `arraysize - 1`.

Maybe the `playlistPos` is being set to `6` inside the Initialization of the Playlist. You should make sure of that.

Comment: But it is part of the array? my code shows that I add the urls to the array

Comment: No, only 6 song are part of the Array, the 7th (6 index) isn't a part of your Array, either its not a part, or its not present in your array. In your code, you have only 6 songs. 7th isn't present; note that referencing to 6 of Array means getting 7th songs from PlayList. Which isn't possible in your code. You should check and minimize the value if its `value > 6` then `value--` :) It would minimize this error.

Comment: Could you show me how I'd implement this into my code?